# Software to record screen when activity

Tags: screen-recording

I'm searching for software that can invisible record the screen when the user is active. I can't find it anywhere.

I've looked at shadowplay and camrecorder but they need user interaction to be turned on.

In my case there is a computer used by teamviewer. I tried to use the teamviewer recording but this does not work out. I want to monitor what people do on the teamviewer session.

Comment: What OS? Gratis or Commercial software?

Comment: Windows 10/8/7 - free would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use OBS (**Open Broadcaster Software**). It is a free open-source software mostly used for live streaming but it can also record your screen.

Why I recommend it?

- Nobody can notice that you are recording because it has no overlay over the screen. But, it still appears in the taskbar. (You can hide the taskbar, or change the icon, etc)
- It does not affect the performance of the PC as much as other recorders. I used it a lot even in games and it is has better performane than Fraps, Action, Camtasia etc.
- It supports Windows 7/8/10

Another suggestion is to use a software that takes screenshots every few seconds. That's what I used when I needed to track down my productivity when working. Most of the times, the applications that take these screenshots are hidden.

EDIT:

Link for OBS: https://obsproject.com/

And here is a tracking printscreen (open-source): https://github.com/ioanb7/TrackingPrintscreen

You can set it up in startup to run when the windows starts.

Comment: Answers here should contain a link to the recommended software so that OP does not need to google. Thanks

Comment: I am currently trying this